# How to deny all the URIs except one in Nginx?

Tags: regex, nginx, pcre, nginx-location, nginx-config

I've a domain where I need to accept only one url and all the other URLs should be blocked. I need to accept only `/page?param=something`. I'm using `Nginx`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something like: `if ($request_uri != /page?param=something) { return 403; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith is there anyway we can use `localtion` directive and `regex` to achieve this. I need to validate the param value.

Comment: The `location` directive cannot be used to match the parameter value.

Comment: @RichardSmith any alternatives?

Comment: You need to check on the `$request_uri`, `$args` or `$arg_param` variable using an `if` or `map` statement. Either can accept regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
map $query_string $is_param {
    ~ param=.+ 1;
}
```

---

```
location ~* /page {
    if ($is_param) {
      allow all;
    }
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: In my answer I used `param=.+`, which match any non-zero length string assigned to `param` parameter. If you need to match some exact word, use `param=word` instead, where `word` is your exact word.

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/questions/947969/filtering-the-query-string-in-nginx